# Get correlations from multiple rows which have the same value (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

So I'm working on a script to compare data and I need to correlate the gathered data. The DataFrame consists of a column of genes which are compared with other genes to get the duplicates. I need a correlation of the genes that have the same duplicate gene.

Example data:
`Index  Gene    Duplicate of  Value1  Value2  Value3  Etc.
0      Gene1   DGene1        0.1     14      13      ..
1      Gene14  DGene1        0       13      17      ..
2      Gene4   DGene3        20      0       0       ..
3      Gene90  DGene3        25      0       10      ..
4      Gene22  DGene31       0       10      0       ..
5      Gene40  DGene31       10      0.5     0       ..
6      Gene130 DGene31       10      1       0       ..
7      Gene600 DGene31       12      0       0       ..`

In case of the example above, I would want three correlations: 1 of genes Gene1 and Gene14, 1 of Gene4 and Gene90 and lastly one of Gene22, Gene40, Gene130 and Gene600. The correlations would exist out of all the values (Value1, etc) from those rows.

I tried to group the data by Duplicate of (CGENE is the Duplicate of),

`df_com2.groupby(CGENE).apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist())`

but I can't find a way to select all values from the corresponding genes after doing so.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try posting some code - you will get better answers

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!
I added the code I used to group the data with, but this is in a later stage of my script and I'm not sure what code would be vital to post for this problem.

Comment: You said "DataFrame" does that mean that you are using pandas ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you're looking for out of the `groupby`, but I suspect you're looking for `.agg` to aggregate fields.

For example, this will give a comma-separated list of genes, and the average of Value1:

```
In [26]: df
Out[26]:
   Index     Gene Duplicate_of  Value1  Value2  Value3 Etc.
0      0    Gene1       DGene1     0.1    14.0      13   ..
1      1   Gene14       DGene1     0.0    13.0      17   ..
2      2    Gene4       DGene3    20.0     0.0       0   ..
3      3   Gene90       DGene3    25.0     0.0      10   ..
4      4   Gene22      DGene31     0.0    10.0       0   ..
5      5   Gene40      DGene31    10.0     0.5       0   ..
6      6  Gene130      DGene31    10.0     1.0       0   ..
7      7  Gene600      DGene31    12.0     0.0       0   ..

In [27]: df.groupby("Duplicate_of").agg({'Gene': ', '.join, 'Value1': np.mean})
Out[27]:
                                          Gene  Value1
Duplicate_of
DGene1                           Gene1, Gene14    0.05
DGene3                           Gene4, Gene90   22.50
DGene31       Gene22, Gene40, Gene130, Gene600    8.00
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! It was indeed an aggregate I was looking for. The only thing I need to figure out now, is how I can correlate the values instead of getting the mean as you have done with `np.mean`.